# Sass interpolate a variable name to string

Tags: sass, interpolation, mixins

We were provided a number of colors with specific hover-state colors associated:

```
$red: #cb333b;
$red-hover: #fe666e;
$brown: #544742;
$brown-hover: #877a75;
etc.
```

Since all the colors are formatted the same way, so I was hoping to write a mixin that takes the color's variable name, then concatenates `-hover` to the end. This is my first try:

```
@mixin button_colorizor($color) {
  border-color: $color;
  color: $color;
  &:hover {
    color: #{$color}-hover;
    border-color: #{$color}-hover;
  }
}
```

But what this does is output a color like this: `#f1735f-hover`. The same thing when I do this: `color: #{$color+-hover};`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501130/is-it-possible-to-nest-variables-within-variables-in-sass

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create map of colors. And get color values by its names.

[Demo](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/1f9ef69393fb1bbdd4740f8ff56b4d70) on sassmeister.

```
$colors: (
  red: #cb333b,
  red-hover: #fe666e,
  brown: #544742,
  brown-hover: #877a75
);

@mixin button_colorizor($color) {
  color: map-get($colors, $color);
  border-color: map-get($colors, $color);

  &:hover {
    color: map-get($colors, $color + '-hover');
    border-color: map-get($colors, $color + '-hover');
  }
}

a {
  @include button_colorizor(red);
}

span {
  @include button_colorizor(brown);
}
```

This code is compiled to css:

```
a {
  color: #cb333b;
  border-color: #cb333b;
}
a:hover {
  color: #fe666e;
  border-color: #fe666e;
}

span {
  color: #544742;
  border-color: #544742;
}
span:hover {
  color: #877a75;
  border-color: #877a75;
}
```

Comment: For posterity, I still used the current variable names.```// Colors variable for use in the colorizor mixin.
$colors: (
  red: $red,
  red-hover: $red-hover,
  peach: $peach,
  peach-hover: $peach-hover,
  brown: $brown,
  brown-hover: $brown-hover,
);```