# SASS call a variable with name is splitted by two

Tags: sass

I am not sure that the title is very inteligible.
Maybe an example would be more effective.

```
$red_500 : #F44336;
$name_1 : "$red";
$name_2 : "_500";

h2{
  color : join($name_1, $name_2);
}

h1{
  color : $red_500;
}
```

In this example, I need the `h2` and the `h1` to have the same color.
In this attempt, the `h1`'s color is : `#F44336`, so it's ok, but the `h2`'s color is : `$red_500`.
Is there any solution to make it working ?
This example is a very simple example, I know this exemple seems stupid as it.

Comment: Yes, it is. Use placeholders instead of variables. See this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501130/is-it-possible-to-nest-variables-within-variables-in-sass

Comment: That's not a solution for me, I've got more than 1000 variables in my file, I'll not make 2 functions per color (text color and background color) :/ So they are no solution ?